# R removing duplicate siblings in xml data

Tags: r, xml, data-science, cosine-similarity

I am working on bugs XML data set:

```
 `</short_desc>     
  <report id="322231">
<update>
  <when>1136281841</when>
  <what>When uploading a objectice-c++ file (.mm) bugzilla sets the MIME type as application/octet-stream</what>
</update>
<update>
  <when>1136420901</when>
  <what>When uploading a objective-c++ file (.mm) bugzilla sets the MIME type as application/octet-stream</what>
</update>
 </report>
</short_desc> `
```

I am creating a data frame from the above xml data by keeping only `<when>` and `<what>` node data. Due to duplicate content in the `<what>` node. I wish to keep only last  node (most recent), if the content of `<what>` node in both the `<update>` is similar. It was supposed to be compared using cosine similarity in R. In case the data in `<what>` node is different, then I want to keep both in the data frame to be created. Please suggest, there are cases when there are more than two updates in single `<report>` and have approximately similar text.

Comment: Please show your effort? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to convert  the xml into data frame and then apply the cosine similarity on to the data frame. But that is not efficient if the size of the dataset is large. I tried on XML siblings but unable to do capture the right nodes.

Comment: Post the code that you have tried so that people can help.

Comment: dtm1 = create_dtm(it1, vectorizer)

dtm2 = create_dtm(it2, vectorizer)

d1_d2_jac_sim = sim2(dtm1, dtm2, method = "jaccard", norm = "none")

d1_d2_jac_dis = dist2(dtm1, dtm2, method = "jaccard", norm = "none")

Comment: your sample data contains a typo in the first <what> objecti`C`e

Answer (score 0):

try the following...

```
library(xml2)
```

**sample data**

```
doc <- read_xml( '<report id="322231">
<update>
                 <when>1136281841</when>
                 <what>When uploading a objective-c++ file (.mm) bugzilla sets the MIME type as application/octet-stream</what>
                 </update>
                 <update>
                 <when>1136420901</when>
                 <what>When uploading a objective-c++ file (.mm) bugzilla sets the MIME type as application/octet-stream</what>
                 </update>
                 </report>')
```

**code**

```
#create nodeset with all 'what'-nodes
what.nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//what" )

#no make a data.frame
df <- data.frame( 
  #get report-attribute "id" by retracing the ancestor tree from the what.nodes
  report_id = xml_attr( xml_find_first( what.nodes, ".//ancestor::report" ), "id" ),
  #get the sibling 'when'  fro the what-node
  when = xml_text( xml_find_first( what.nodes, ".//preceding-sibling::when" ) ),
  #get 'what'
  what = xml_text( what.nodes ),
  #set stringsAsfactors
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

#get rows with unique values from the bottom-up
df[ !duplicated( df$what, fromLast = TRUE ), ]
```

**output**

```
#   report_id       when                                                                                              what
# 2    322231 1136420901 When uploading a objective-c++ file (.mm) bugzilla sets the MIME type as application/octet-stream
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply